# Yandex MapKit 3 - поймать центр экрана (камеры) и использовать зум, показать местоположение

Tags: android, yandex-maps-api, карты, yandexmapkit

Создал карту. Добавил кнопочки для управления, но не могу найти методы для зума и центровки экрана. Вот примерно что получилось:

```
private final Point DRIVER_POSITION = new Point(56.844213, 53.242305);
private final Point CLIENT_POSITION = new Point(56.8710986, 53.2867346);
private final Point SCREEN_CENTER = new Point(
        (DRIVER_POSITION.getLatitude() + CLIENT_POSITION.getLatitude()) / 2,
        (DRIVER_POSITION.getLongitude() + CLIENT_POSITION.getLongitude()) / 2);
private float zoom = 11.0f,
        azimuth = 0.0f, tilt = 0.0f;
...
@Override
protected void initViews() {
    presenter.loadData();
    mapObjects = mapView.getMap().getMapObjects().addCollection();
    //createMapObjects();
    zoomUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mapView.getMap().move(new CameraPosition(
                    SCREEN_CENTER, getZoom()+1, azimuth, tilt));
        }
    });
    zoomDown.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mapView.getMap().move(new CameraPosition(
                    SCREEN_CENTER, getZoom()-1, azimuth, tilt));
        }
    });
    positionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ////
        }
    });
}
.....
@Override
public void showDefaultData(String balance, String lat, String lon) {
    tvBalance.setText(balance);
    mapView.getMap().move(
            new CameraPosition(new Point(Double.valueOf(lat),                         
Double.valueOf(lon)), zoom, azimuth, tilt),
            new Animation(Animation.Type.SMOOTH, 0),
            null);
    mapView.getMap().move(new CameraPosition(
            SCREEN_CENTER, zoom-6, azimuth, tilt));
    drivingRouter = MapKitFactory.getInstance().createDrivingRouter();
    mapObjects = mapView.getMap().getMapObjects().addCollection();
    submitRequest();
    showPosition();
}
```

Что я делаю не так? Я изучил документацию, но разобраться, осилить её не смог

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственно вот так решил свою проблему:

```
//Ваше местоположение. Point
private Point DRIVER_POSITION = new Point(56.844213, 53.242305);
.....
//События нажатий на кнопки. FAB Button's
.....
    zoomUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mapView.getMap().move(new CameraPosition(mapView.getMap().getCameraPosition().getTarget(),
                    mapView.getMap().getCameraPosition().getZoom()+1, 0.0f, 0.0f),
                    new Animation(Animation.Type.SMOOTH, 1),
                    null);
        }
    });
    zoomDown.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mapView.getMap().move(new CameraPosition(mapView.getMap().getCameraPosition().getTarget(),
                    mapView.getMap().getCameraPosition().getZoom()-1, 0.0f, 0.0f),
                    new Animation(Animation.Type.SMOOTH, 1),
                    null);
        }
    });
    positionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mapView.getMap().move(
                    new CameraPosition(userLocationLayer.cameraPosition().getTarget(), 15.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
                    new Animation(Animation.Type.SMOOTH, 1),
                    null);
        }
    });
   .....
public void showPosition() {
    userLocationLayer = mapView.getMap().getUserLocationLayer();
    userLocationLayer.setEnabled(true);
    userLocationLayer.setHeadingEnabled(true);
    userLocationLayer.setObjectListener(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Может быть кому-то будет полезно.
Получить точку-центр экрана:

```
Point point = mapView.getMap().getCameraPosition().getTarget();
```